# Custom rake tasks with metaprogramming for Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, capistrano3

I'd like to run custom rake tasks on remote server with Capistrano.

I have the following code:

```
# cap production rake:db:seed
namespace :rake do
  namespace :db do
    %w|migrate reset rollback seed|.each do |command|
      desc "Rake db:#{command}"
      task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
        run "cd #{fetch(:deploy_to)}/current"
        run "bundle exec rake db:#{ENV['task']} RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:rails_env)}"
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

But metaprogramming doesn't work. I got the following error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method`tail' for nil:NilClass`

Of course, I can make the task as following:

```
  # cap production rake:invoke task=db:seed
  desc "Invoke rake task"
  task :invoke do
    run "cd #{fetch(:deploy_to)}/current"
    run "bundle exec rake #{ENV['task']} RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:rails_env)}"
  end
```

But I'd prefer the first approach.

Why first approach doesn't work?

Comment: What's the stacktrace?

Comment: My Trace: http://pastie.org/9000836

Comment: What's in `ENV['task']`? perhaps you meant to write `"bundle exec rake db:#{command} RAILS_ENV=#{fetch(:rails_env)}"`?